# Problem with my Wordpress CSS version Cache updating

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a blog on Wordpress. I usually update my CSS file, the CSS file have a tag like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rit-style-css'  href='https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/themes/ri-maxazine/ri-maxazine/style.css?ver=5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

You can see live here: https://www.lagaleramagazine.es

The problem is that the browser don't update my file, it's keeping the same version (5.2), so the changes that I did to the file didn't show.

I tried to search the CSS file on .php file on my theme but I can't get it to work.

If you visit the file with https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/themes/ri-maxazine/ri-maxazine/style.css?ver=5.3 you will see a differente version that https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/themes/ri-maxazine/ri-maxazine/style.css?ver=5.2.

I searched a solution but the problem is I can't find the CSS line tag on my Wordpress php files:

```
/css/style.css?v=<?php echo date('his'); ?>
```

(I don't know it this will work)

Comment: Your enqueue of style.css should be found in functions.php - Note that date will make it so that it is never cached. But you could set the versioning to the last date the file was modified

Comment: How I can do that? "t you could set the versioning to the last date the file was modified"

Comment: you could use `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' )`  as the last parameter of your enqueue

Comment: this is best in a child theme though, since you will loose this on updates if you do it in a parent theme

Comment: @Stender your code didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found of forcing a stylesheet to enqueue the latest version is using the `filemtime()` function, which will use the modified date of the file as the latest version. That way it will be relatively cache friendly but also update when the style is.

e.g.

```php
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rit-style-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime(  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
```

Make sure to put it in a function that's added to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action if it's not already.

If you're working in a child theme or similar then you'll need to dequeue the file before enqueuing it again.

```php
function example_update_stylesheet(){

       wp_dequeue_style( 'rit-style-css' );

       wp_enqueue_style( 'rit-style-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime(  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_update_stylesheet', 100 ); /*Late priority*/
```

Comment: Not working for me, sorry. It keeping without updating

Comment: Can you try just doing the dequeue action without re-enqueueing it? To see if that works.